# Create an array of objects in javascript for knockout observableArray([])

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create below "OutputArray" from "InputObject". I've created a function getdata() which converts the two objects. 
When I write these objects to the console in chrome they are displayed slightly differently, Screenshots are below.

**OuputObect:** (This is my desired output)

```
{
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Name the color",
            "q" : "what is the color white in HTML",
            "a" : "255 255 255",
            "video" : "http://aws.asdfsadf.com/something.mkv",
            "images" : {
                "title" : "White Image",
                "url" : "http://aws.asdfsdf.com/image.jpg"
                }
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "Name the color",
            "q" : "what is the color black in HTML",
            "a" : "0 0 0",
            "video" : "http://aws.asdfsadf.com/something.mkv",
            "images" : {
                "title" : "White Image",
                "url" : "http://aws.asdfsdf.com/image.jpg"
        }
}
```

**OutputObject should appear in chrome like this:** console.log(OutputObject)

[image: Correct output]

**Instead it looks like this:** console.log(getdata(InputObject))

[image: Incorrect output]

**InputObject:** (This is how the data is presented by FireDB)

```
{
        "1" : {
            "name" : "Name the color",
            "q" : "what is the color white in HTML",
            "a" : "255 255 255",
            "video" : "http://aws.asdfsadf.com/something.mkv",
            "images" : {
                "title" : "White Image",
                "url" : "http://aws.asdfsdf.com/image.jpg"
                }
        },
        "2" : {
            "name" : "Name the color",
            "q" : "what is the color black in HTML",
            "a" : "0 0 0",
            "video" : "http://aws.asdfsadf.com/something.mkv",
            "images" : {
                "title" : "White Image",
                "url" : "http://aws.asdfsdf.com/image.jpg"
                }
        }

    }
```

**getdata() function...**

```
function getdata(data){

    var array = [];

    for (var key in data) {

        var arrayObject = {};

        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        var obj = jsondata.questions[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            // skip loop if the property is from prototype
            if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            arrayObject[prop] = obj[prop];
            }

        arrayObject["id"] = key;
        array.push(arrayObject)
    }
return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that both arrays are equal, they are just displayed differently in chrome.

My issue was that I was calling ko.observableArray([OutputObject])

(with square brackets)

Instead of:

ko.observableArray(getdata(OutputObject));